# Is there credible evidence that a child using an iPad will have their eyesight affected?

Tags: medical-science, safety, technology

I have been told by several people that allowing my young children (aged 2 and 5 at the time of writing) to use an iPad, or similar device, would affect their eyesight. I have found the following articles that appear to support this claim.

http://news.ninemsn.com.au/health/8476967/ditch-the-ipad-and-send-kids-out-to-play

http://usa.chinadaily.com.cn/china/2012-03/09/content_14793242.htm

http://www.globaltimes.cn/NEWS/tabid/99/ID/706432/iPad-or-iBad-The-notebook-might-look-cool-but-what-is-it-doing-to-children.aspx

The impression seems to be that children should be avoiding using this kind of device until they are at least 7 years old.

Is there any more recent scientific evidence to back up this claim than the surveys in 2007 which were before the introduction of the iPad?

Comment: You need to find a source for the claim. Otherwise the claim isn't notable and this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: OK - will do. Back in a mo...

Comment: I find these claims bizarre, what changes in a child between 6years364days and the very next day that suddenly their eyesight will be unaffected.

Comment: @Jamiec I think it's more about creating a suitable marker point where the effect has been reduced so low as to be negligible. I feel I must link to the obligatory XKCD: http://xkcd.com/605/

Comment: AFAIK, there are scientific studies showing that you shouldn't use tablets, but it's because of neck strain, not eyes.